# What is the cause of this segmentation fault: 11 error?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program in C that reads in a positive integer of up to 20 digits. It should output the smallest palindromic number that is higher than the input. A palindromic number is one that is the same when its digits are reversed (e.g, 98789 is a palindrome, 12344321 is a palindrome, 12345 is not a palindrome as it becomes 54321 when reversed). A sample run, for example, would take 17 as an input and output 22. However, when I run the program and place an input, a segmentation fault: 11 error occurs. Please note that I'm not an experienced programmer, so the code might seem ugly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long reversed(unsigned long palindrome);

int main() {
  unsigned long palindrome;
  scanf("%lu", &palindrome);

  while(1) {
    palindrome++;

    if (palindrome == reversed(palindrome)) {
      printf("%lu", reversed(palindrome));
      break;
    }
  }
}

unsigned long reversed(unsigned long palindrome) {
  int size = 0;
  unsigned long copy = palindrome;
  while(copy != 0) {
    copy /= 10;
    size++;
  }

  int count = 0;
  unsigned long arr[size];
  while (palindrome != 0) {
    arr[count] = palindrome % 10;
    count++;
  }

  unsigned long reverse = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    reverse *= 10;
    reverse += arr[i];
  }
  return reverse;
}
```

The error seems to suggest that I'm accessing a memory location that I shouldn't be accessing, but I don't understand the actual cause of this. Does it have to do with the unsigned longs or the array? I appreciate any advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error seems to be caused by this loop probably.

```
while (palindrome != 0) {
    arr[count] = palindrome % 10;
    count++;
  }
```

you are not changing the value of `palindrome` inside this loop, but the value of `count` is increasing causing you to access a memory which is out of bounds when `count` becomes greater then `size`

Comment: Can't believe I didn't notice that. I should be doing palindrome /= 10. Thank you very much